# randomly select a color from a premade list

Tags: java, random, colors

I want to randomly select a color from a premade list of colors and I'm not sure how to go about it.  Something like this:

```
String[] randomColor = {"BLUE", "GREEN", "CYAN",
        "RED", "YELLOW", "MAGENTA", "PINK"};
x = (Math.random() * 6)
graphics.setColor(Color.x);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  `Random.nextInt(6)` instead. But this won't work the way you want. You can't reference an object using the string name. You will need to put the `Color` object inside a `Color` array: `Color[]`

```
   Color[] colors = { Color.red, Color.blue, Color.white, Color.cyan, 
                      Color.green, Color.gray, new Color(0xFFAA00) };
   Random random = new Random();
   int x = random.nextInt(colors.length);
   graphics.setColor(colors[x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
randomColor[new Random().nextInt(randomColor.length)]
```